# What does this mean? Boolean Header

Tags: java, boolean

What does `public boolean identical(Formula f)`

Can someone break down what each word means and explain it to me?

Comment: Please look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: @npinti +1 for a truly constructive, non-judgmental comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the start of the declaration of a method named `identical` that accepts a `Formula` object as an argument and returns a `boolean` value (`true` or `false`). Because the method is declared `public` it can be called from any code for which the containing class is accessible. Inside the method, the passed argument can be referenced as `f`.

Answer (score 1):

`public` goes for the visibility of your method in your code.

`boolean` is the return type of your method.

`identical` is the name of the method.

`Formula` is the datatype of the parameter passed (Class in your case)

`f` is the object of the class Formula that is the passed as an argument to the method identical.